# My gridview doesn't show in Browser due to parameter value

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I am using ASP.net and at some point I have a gridview that doesn't show up in my browser when I debug my project. On that same page do I use a textbox and that one does show up.

This is the HTML.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/SvShop.Master" CodeBehind="Mijnoverzicht.aspx.vb" Inherits="SvShop.Mijnoverzicht" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


<h1>Mijn Artikelen</h1>


<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMijnEmail" runat="server" CssClass="tekstvak" Width="190px"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
            </tr>
    </table>



<div class="OverzichtMijn">


    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewMijn" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="MijnDataSource" AllowSorting="True" Width="845px">

        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ArtikelBeschrijving" HeaderText="Beschrijving" SortExpression="ArtikelBeschrijving" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ArtikelPrijs" HeaderText="Prijs" SortExpression="ArtikelPrijs" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ArtikelAankoopdatum" HeaderText="Aankoopdatum" SortExpression="ArtikelAankoopdatum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ArtikelTekoopgezet" HeaderText="Tekoopgezet" SortExpression="ArtikelTekoopgezet" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GebruikersNaam" HeaderText="Naam" SortExpression="GebruikersNaam" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GebruikersVoornaam" HeaderText="Voornaam" SortExpression="GebruikersVoornaam" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GebruikersEmail" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="GebruikersEmail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GebruikersGSM" HeaderText="GSM" SortExpression="GebruikersGSM" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle CssClass="GridViewEditRow" />
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MijnDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SvShopInternString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SvShopInternString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT tblArtikel.ArtikelBeschrijving, tblArtikel.ArtikelPrijs, tblArtikel.ArtikelAankoopdatum, tblArtikel.ArtikelTekoopgezet, tblGebruiker.GebruikersNaam, tblGebruiker.GebruikersVoornaam, tblGebruiker.GebruikersEmail, tblGebruiker.GebruikersGSM FROM ((tblArtikel INNER JOIN tblGebruiker ON tblArtikel.GebruikersID = tblGebruiker.GebruikersID) INNER JOIN tblRubriek ON tblArtikel.RubriekID = tblRubriek.RubriekID) WHERE (tblGebruiker.GebruikersEmail = '@Email')"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the browser view.
[image: Browser View]

The problem should be in this line of code.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MijnDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SvShopInternString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SvShopInternString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT tblArtikel.ArtikelBeschrijving, tblArtikel.ArtikelPrijs, tblArtikel.ArtikelAankoopdatum, tblArtikel.ArtikelTekoopgezet, tblGebruiker.GebruikersNaam, tblGebruiker.GebruikersVoornaam, tblGebruiker.GebruikersEmail, tblGebruiker.GebruikersGSM FROM ((tblArtikel INNER JOIN tblGebruiker ON tblArtikel.GebruikersID = tblGebruiker.GebruikersID) INNER JOIN tblRubriek ON tblArtikel.RubriekID = tblRubriek.RubriekID) WHERE (tblGebruiker.GebruikersEmail = '@Email')"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The parameter
    @Email
gets his value from the textbox above with this code:

```
Protected Sub txtMijnEmail_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtMijnEmail.TextChanged
    MijnDataSource.SelectCommand.Replace("@Email", txtMijnEmail.Text)
GridViewMijn.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: is your datasource returning any records? If not, the gridview won't show.

Comment: No it doesn't because I want to show only the rows `"SELECT * WHERE email = '" & txtEmail.text & "'"`

Comment: That's the answer then. The gridview has no records to show since your textbox is empty.

Comment: But is there an other way to only show the data depending to what the user filled in?

Comment: now sure what you mean

Comment: if your datasource is setup correctly (seams like it's not, dont see any parameters defined), you need to do a post back and databind the greed

Comment: This is an e-commerce I am making and when the users gives in his email in the textbox above, he must be able to see in the gridview what items he is selling.

Comment: postback is required. Like through a button click. On button click `GridViewMijn.DataBind()`

Comment: at the moment I use `txtEmail_TextChanged` why isn't that working?

Comment: because that event doesn't cause a postback.

Comment: So I must use a button instead of text_changed

Comment: yes, or make a postback happen via javascript event.

Comment: The button doesn't work. it does nothing.

Comment: First of all, you sqldatasource doesn't have any parameters defined. second, you must databind your grid on button click.

Comment: oh ok, MijnDataSource.SelectCommand.Replace("@Email", txtMijnEmail.Text) and then GridViewMijn.DataBind()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111451/discussion-between-thimo-demey-and-boruchsiper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overkill - just add a Control Parameter to the SelectParameters:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MijnDataSource" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SvShopInternString %>"
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SvShopInternString.ProviderName %>" 

      SelectCommand="SELECT <snip> WHERE (tblGebruiker.GebruikersEmail = '@Email')">

      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter 
              ControlID="txtMijnEmail" 
              PropertyName="Text" 
              Name="Email">
          </asp:ControlParameter>
      </SelectParameters>

  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And obviously make sure your Select command returns a dataset when a valid email is provided.

Also consider temporarily setting `GridViewMijn.ShowHeader="true"` and `GridViewMijn.EmptyDataText="No Data returned"` for debugging purposes

Comment: Thank you, I did the same as you just answered but I did it in Design instead of code.

Comment: In the end it amounts to the same thing. Directly changing the .aspx will become second nature once you're familiar with the aspx markup. That's all the designer is doing.  It'll come.